# Call WCF in Xamarin

Tags: wcf, xamarin

I am kindof new to xamarin and WCF. 
I create a wcf Project

```
namespace playforme
{

    public class activatepin : Iactivatepin
    {
        public string validatepin(int pin)
        {
            if (pin > 0)
            {
                return "You entered value";
            }
            else { return "No value entered"; }        
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace playforme
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface Iactivatepin 
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string validatepin(int pin);
    }
}
```

In my Xamarin APP, I have this

```
playerni.activatepin ws = new playerni.activatepin();

string msg = ws.validatepin(23) ;
```

I get this error: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter".

Comment: Seems like you are new to WCF,know the basics of WCF.Refer this http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/p/wcf-tutorial.html and then try to consume the service via our XAMARIN app.

Comment: @Hameed Syed your feedback is crude

Comment: No,I didnt mean to be or I am rude.See there are lot of things in WCF ,before this ou have to know starter basics.

Comment: WCF is cumbersome, legacy and discontinued. If you're building something new you'll have an easier time using modern technologies like Rest & Swagger (I'm aware I'm not answering your question but the sooner you abandon WCF the more headaches you'll save yourself)

Comment: @Thibault thanks so much, I have been able to get through with REST which was more simpler